How to count the number of rows that meet a boolean condition?
I have two tables that are compared against each other, row by row, to make a third table.  The third table is a schedule meant to be quickly interpreted by humans, and therefore is composed of a bunch of blank cells with conditionally formatted colors: it contains no actual data.
The conditionals that turn the schedule cells various colors are well-developed, but I cannot figure out a scalable way to count the number of times a particular condition returns TRUE (and therefore the number of times a given color appears in a given column).
I thought about using an intermediary table of IFS, but I'd like to avoid that since it would require rebuilding the program from the ground up.
A sanitized version of the data can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6g-Tvlq_FeR_ktwqz2EnywB_BOcPj3kenb0jV-3SWw/edit?usp=sharing
The idea is to count the number of timeslots where each task is indicated as green.  The rule that turns timeslots green is =let(Σ,filter($C5:$J5,filter(INDIRECT("Quals!$G$6:$N$100"),INDIRECT("Quals!$B6:$B100")=L$3)="Y"),countif(Σ,"Y")=columns(Σ))  In the picture below, the desired output is highlighted in cyan.


you can use the COUNTIF or the SUMPRODUCT functions.

I cannot, because there is nothing in the cells to count.  Unless I misunderstand COUNTIF, finding a way to put intermediary data in the cells at this point would be an enormous undertaking.

we don't know how your data looks like so it's difficult to help. But if you are coloring cells with a conditional formatting rule there's surely a way to create a formula that counts the cells that meet that rule. If you share more details we can help.

Today I learned COUNTIF is much more versatile than I thought.  I added a link to the data.  The problem now centers around performing row-by-row analysis while dumping the output of the COUNTIF into a single cell.


You may try:
=map(L3:Y3,lambda(Λ,sum(byrow(C5:J20,lambda(Δ,let(Σ,filter(Δ,filter(Quals!G6:N100,Quals!B6:B100=Λ)="Y"),--(countif(Σ,"Y")=columns(Σ))))))))


